# How to check if a particular bit in a buffer is set in C#

Tags: c#

I have a c# code which write a hex code to a port for a device. The device reply for the port, I read his answer, I transformed it to a hex and disply it in a text box.
So, now I must to check each bits from the answer and display a message in a text box or somthing like that.

Can anybody help me please?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: have you looked into bit operators? (`<<` , `>>` , `&` etc)

Comment: Indeed - what have you tried?

Comment: I tried to save response in a buffer and transform from hex to binary string. I checked in this buffer each bit but I could not display the message which I want (Ex. if the third bit is 1 serial communication is ok else serial communication error).

Comment: Yes elyashiv I looked there. My problem is how I make a link between condition that bit x to be set ok and display "ok" message in a text box?

Answer (score 2):

Bitwise AND your response with the bit you want to check:

```
Byte response = (Byte)0xFF;
Boolean isBitOneSet = (response & 0x1) > 0;
Boolean isBitTwoSet = (response & 0x2) > 0;
Boolean isBitThreeSet = (response & 0x4) > 0;
```

Or use right-shift:

```
Boolean isBitFiveSet = ((response >> 4) & 0x1) > 0;

if(isBitFiveSet) System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("Five is set");
```

Comment: Many thanks for your help Ferdinand, but System.Windows.MessageBox.Show not help me. I want to show "" Five bit is set" in my GUI in a specific text box.

Comment: myTextBox.Text = "Five is set";

Comment: I still have probleme. I will present here my code maybe you can help me more

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Convert.ToString()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14kwkz77.aspx) method if you need binary representation of a number - it is much simpler and efficient than checking every single bit separately. This method can convert to binary and HEX format - whatever you like.

Comment: I don't need binary representation, I have to check each bit from every byte. My answer from the device have 13 bytes in HEX format, so I have to check 104 bits.

Comment: I have to do 2 thinks:
1. Firstly I must check every bite
2.Secondly I want display one message in a text box if second, or third, etc bite is ok or not ok set (if x bite is set 1 "Serial comunication ok, else Serial communication error, etc")

Comment: Then I agree with Ferdinand's recommendation. But it is better to replace ">0" with "!=0". Because if you once will check integers, you can get negative values.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Oleksandr. I still have problem.I post my c# code here. Many thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
namespace read_display_data
```

{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

```
    SerialPort port = new SerialPort("COM1", 19200, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);


    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        port.Open();
        port.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(port_DataReceived);

    }

    private void Sendbutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        port.Write(new byte[] { 0x55, 0x08, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x03, 0x5D }, 0, 8)
        byte[] buffer1 = new byte[] { 0x55, 0x08, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x03, 0x5D };

        Log1(LogMsgType.Outgoing, DateTime.Now + "  --  " + ByteArrayToHexString(buffer1) + "\n");

    }


    public enum LogMsgType { Incoming, Outgoing, Normal };

    void port_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {

        int bytes = port.BytesToRead;

        byte[] buffer = new byte[bytes];

        port.Read(buffer, 0, bytes);

        Thread.Sleep(100);

        Log(LogMsgType.Incoming, DateTime.Now + "  --  " + ByteArrayToHexString(buffer) + "\n");
        Log2(LogMsgType.Incoming, DateTime.Now + "  --  " + GetInBinaryString(buffer) + "\n");


    }


    private string ByteArrayToHexString(byte[] buffer)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(buffer.Length * 3);
        foreach (byte b in buffer)
            sb.Append(Convert.ToString(b, 16).PadLeft(2, '0').PadRight(3, ' '));
        return sb.ToString().ToUpper();


    }


    private string GetInBinaryString(byte[] buffer)
    {

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(buffer.Length * 8);
        foreach (byte b in buffer)
            sb.Append(Convert.ToString(b, 2).PadLeft(8, '0').PadRight(5, ' '));
        return sb.ToString().ToUpper();




    }

    private void Log(LogMsgType msgtype, string msg)
    {
        textBox1.Invoke(new EventHandler(delegate
        {
            textBox1.SelectedText = string.Empty;
            textBox1.AppendText(msg);
            textBox1.ScrollToCaret();

        }
        ));


    }
    private void Log1(LogMsgType msgtype, string msg)
    {
        textBox2.Invoke(new EventHandler(delegate
        {
            textBox2.SelectedText = string.Empty;
            textBox2.AppendText(msg);
            textBox2.ScrollToCaret();

        }
        ));


    }


    private void Log2(LogMsgType msgtype, string msg)
    {
        textBox3.Invoke(new EventHandler(delegate
        {
            textBox3.SelectedText = string.Empty;
            textBox3.AppendText(msg);
            textBox3.ScrollToCaret();

        }
        ));


    }
```

Comment: This is my c# code and I still have problems with it.Can anybody help me please?

Comment: Could you describe your new problem? In your first post you said you can't convert binary to string. Now it should work I think (not sure though if it is the most efficient implementation with PadLeft and PadRight). So what doesn't work as expected? Are you sure "port_DataReceived" method called? is anything appear in the textBox1?

Comment: I received in textbox the response from the device. This think is ok.The response is a hex which lenght is 13. I want to check each bite from each byte from the hex and display in another text box ok message if bit is set or error if bit is'n set.

Comment: I don't know if the conversion is the best way to do solve my problem too. I am thinking to solve it with a mask but if I want to check each bit from eack byte I must make a very large number of masks...I realy don't know how to do it with efficinecy

Comment: Know my code do this: When I press the sendButton write to port 1 which is set this hex:0x55, 0x08, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x03, 0x5D and display it in textBox2 too. The device respond with a hex and display it in textBox1. In textBox3 display the response in binary format.

Answer (score 0):

Ferdinand already described the way you can check individual bits. Maybe it wasnt clear enough though.

So to check every bit in every byte you should white the code like this:

```
StringBuilder message = new StringBuilder();
for (int byteNum = 0; byteNum < bytes.Length; byteNum++)
{
  var responseByte = bytes[byteNum];
  for (int bitPos = 0; bitPos < 8; bitPos++)
  {
    message.AppendFormat("Byte {0} bit {1} value is {2}", byteNum, bitPos, (responseByte & (1<<bitPos)) != 0);
  }
}
```

Hope now it's more clear. The only thing you night want to change is byte and bit order. I don't know for sure how bit sequence is converted to byte array: the 0th bit really might have came the last in the byte.

Comment: Many thanks for your help. I hope to understand your explanations and do it as soon as possible

Comment: I manage to make it work, finnaly. Thank you for your help Oleksandr

Comment: I solve that probleme like I said but I realised that I have another one when a read data from the device. I didn't receive all bytes in same time. Do you have any idea why Oleksandr? I think the buffer I made isn't work correct, but why?

Comment: I solv this probleme too.Thank you very much!